# Menu building - Wicket framework

Tags: wicket

I am building a two-level menu for my application using wicket framework. Using ListView#populateItem is redrawing the markup (SubMenuPanel.html) and unable to display menu items which were buried inside markup tags in SubMenuPanel.html. Code below -

html:

```
<div wicket:id="navMenu"></div>
```

Main.java:

```
NavigationMenu navigationMenu = new NavigationMenu("navMenu", navigationMenuAdapter);
add(navigationMenu);
```

NavigationMenu.java

```
public NavigationMenu(final String id, final NavigationMenuAdapter adapter)
{
    super(id);
    this.adapter = adapter;
    add(new SubMenuPanel("mainMenu", adapter.getNavigationMenus(this)));
}
```

SubMenuPanel.java

```
public SubMenuPanel(final String id, List<NavigationMenuItem> list)
{
    super(id);
    add(new Rows("firstLevel", list));
    setVersioned(false);
}

private static class Rows extends ListView<NavigationMenuItem>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Rows(String name, List<NavigationMenuItem> list)
    {
        super(name, list);
    }

    @Override
    protected void populateItem(ListItem<NavigationMenuItem> listItem)
    {
        Object modelObject = listItem.getDefaultModelObject();

        WebMarkupContainer rowAnchor = new WebMarkupContainer("firstLevelLink");
        rowAnchor.add(new Label("firstLevelLabel", ((NavigationMenuItem) modelObject).getName()));
        rowAnchor.add(new AttributeAppender("onclick", new Model("handleMenuClick()");
        listItem.add(rowAnchor);

        listItem.add(new SubMenuPanel("secondLevelMenu", ((NavigationMenuItem) modelObject).getChildMenuItem()));

    }
}
```

SubMenuPanel.html

```
<body>
<wicket:panel>
     <li wicket:id="firstLevel">    
        <a wicket:id="firstLevelLink" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:void(0);" >
            <span wicket:id="firstLevelLabel"></span>
        </a>

        <ul wicket:id="secondLevelMenu" class="dropdown-menu">

        </ul>
    </li>                         
</wicket:panel>
```

Working version
[image]

Non-working
[image]

Comment: Could you paste some example output and describe what's wrong with it?

Comment: WiseTree - Updated the question with menu images that I am getting.. Items under Heading1 are not coming up.. As this line 'listItem.add(new SubMenuPanel("secondLevelMenu", ((NavigationMenuItem) modelObject).getChildMenuItem()));' is recursive, seems markup in SubMenuPanel.html is redrawn..

Comment: Could you paste the markup for the incorrect output?